# replacement for Microsoft ExpressionWeb 4

Tags: html, ide

As per subject I would like to find a WISIWYG IDE, cross platform preferred, to replace my use of Microsoft ExpressionWeb 4.
Googling has not turned up anything with a live view

Comment: Free or paid?  Specific feature set?

Comment: @SiXandSeventh*ths Either free or paid - no real preference. Minimal feature set - syntax validation, highlighting, code completion, snippets. Tried Dreamweaver - way to complicated and feature heavy for what I do. Tried Sublime Text 3  - need plugins for almost everything. Couldn't get "View in Browser" plugin to work; no replies from their forum. Most important - entering text in live view (as in ExpressionWeb) so you don't have to constantly switch from content to code.

Comment: SiXandSeven8ths just correcting your id (my mistake) to make sure you see response

Comment: I don't have a good answer to this one, since you already tried Dreamweaver....aside from price, that's what I'd recommend for a good WYSIWYG as there aren't too many choices out there.  Anything else I've seen is looks pretty sub-par (haven't tried some of them out though).  I agree it is complex and has a lot of features.  I'm going to research this a bit more and if there aren't any answers by the time I find something I'll post what I come up with.  This is something I'm interested in as well.  Hopefully someone else has some suggestions.